# Access index of a value on an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

My question : I want to randomly access an index from my objects key values.

I'm trying to create a text based adventure game. I have an element that will display different texts and button options based on the 'quest' you are on. I want it to randomly choose a quest from my quest objects.

For example: I will have a key with the name of the quest for example : "Dragon Slayer" then a key called text which will have a string value: "Do you want to kill a dragon"

I expected to achieve this with an object...

```js
const quest = {
  dragonFight: {
    text: "you are fighting dragon",
    button1: "fight",
    button2: "flee"
  } //etc for others.
}
```

upon trying to randomly get one of the values, I realised I wasn't able to access the values like an array index. I thought I could use something along the lines of this..

```
var mainQuest = Math.floor(Math.random()* Quest[0].length);

displayText = Quest[mainQuest[mainQuest].title]
```

Comment: `Object.keys()`, `Object.entries()`

Comment: Why not turn your quest into an array? Seems to be the best solution if you want to build a list of quest objects... and then you can pretty easily access them randomly, or simply randomize the array and access it sequentially...

Comment: It was more so I could have it more organised the quests into categorised and named groups instead of just index's.  Thats the idea that I had anyways but an array is looking like the easier option right now. But I'm learning something new with objects so I don't mind taking the extra time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andreas has the correct answer, the implementation is basically:

```
let keys=Object.keys(quest)
let index=Math.floor(Math.random()*keys.length)
randomQuest=quest[keys[index]]
```

And `randomQuest` would be the randomly selected quest :D

Comment: Thank you so much ! Really appreciate it